# How to calculate odds

Tags: statistics

Tim hortons has a roll-up the rim to win contents.  your chances of winning in a single play is 1 in 6.  so you have a 5/6 (83% chance) of winning nothing.

How do I calculate the odds of losing multiple times in a row?  In 2 plays, what are my chances of losing both times?  and what are my chances of losing 41 times in a row?  because that's what I'm at now?

Comment: There is a 0.05% chance of losing 41 times in a row. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer Ross Millikan gave applies if you have played $41$ times and lost every time. However, the chance that you will have a streak of at least $41$ losses at some point is $1$ if you keep playing. Did you play a total of $41$ times, or did you have some successes before the streak of $41$ losses?

The average wait between streaks of length at least $L$ is $p^{-L}/(1-p)$, where $p$ is the chance of "success" or $5/6$ here. For $L=41$, you have to wait about $10,582$ trials between streaks of length $41$.

The probability that there is a streak of length at least $L$ in a session of length $S$ where $S$ is much bigger than $L$ is about $1-\exp(-(S-L)/\text{average wait})$. By exact calculations with transfer matrices, the probability that you have a streak of length at least $41$ in $100$ trials is $0.614\%$. In $1000$ trials it is $8.748\%$. These are close to the estimates of $0.556\%$ and $8.664\%$.

Comment: A group of us (cube mates) at work, keep track of total losses since the last win.  Since the last time anyone won, there have been 41 losses with no wins.  I figured the odds of of 41 losses seemed very low considering Tim Hortins publishes that the chance of winning is 1 in 6.  However, there is a finite number of prizes, so each time a prize is one, it is removed from the possible pool of prizes.

Comment: Good point about the specification of the problem.  On the other hand, the losing streak is one-sided (still continuing) instead of any time in a long string.  Many of these probability things depend very sensitively on the assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the chances are independent, the probabilities are multiplied.  So you would say the chance of losing $n$ in a row is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n$  For $n=2$, this is $\frac{25}{36}$ or just over $\frac{2}{3}$.  As Zach says, for $n=41$ this is $0.05\%$, so maybe you want to revise your estimate of the chance of winning.